# Orthogonal projection of a matrix onto the line

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

I have the following exercise:

Let $V = W = \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $f$ be the mapping given by
the orthogonal projection onto the line passing through the points (0, 0)
and (3, 2). Let E = {$e_1$, $e_2$} = $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\right\}$.
and let B = {$v_1$, $v_2$} = $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 2 
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}
\right\}$. Find $[$f$]_B$->$_B$.

Need some advice on how to find this does it has to do with the projection or I am complety missunderstanding it?